# Cross product in 3D

Tags: tikz-pgf

How can I draw this picture using Tikz?[image]

Comment: And how can I mark angles between all three vectors?

Comment: Have you had a look at the tikz manual?

Comment: What is exactly your doubt? Drawing an arrow? Drawing a line? Colouring things? Adding a node? Here it's preferred if you don't just ask “do it for me, please”. What is exactly your doubt here? What have you written so far? Add a compilable example of what you've got and someone will take it from there. If your only doubt is how to mark an angle, just ask that.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX](//tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436). Questions about how to draw specific graphics that just post an image of the desired result are really not reasonable questions to ask on the site. Please post a minimal compilable document showing that you've tried to produce the image and then people will be happy to help you with any specific problems you may have.  See [minimal working example (MWE)](//tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) for what needs to go into such a document.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to create a cross product with tikz?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/302490/how-to-create-a-cross-product-with-tikz) or https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/341567/tikz-package-for-planes

Comment: Definitely not a duplicate. That other thing appears to be some entirely different way to setup a cross product. I've definitely found this question and the responses far more useful than the linked one that it is marked as a duplicate for :)

Comment: Please note: This question is about *drawing* a cross product, not *computing* a cross product.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This really doesn't require any special library or so.

```
\documentclass[border=3pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[-,fill=white!95!red](0,0)--(3,0)--(4,1)--(1,1)--cycle;
\node at (2,0.5) {$|\textcolor{blue}{a}\times \textcolor{red}{b}|$};
\draw[ultra thick,-latex,blue](0,0)--(3,0)node[midway,below]{$a$};
\draw[ultra thick,-latex,red](0,0)--(1,1)node[midway,above]{$b$};
\draw[ultra thick,-latex,blue!50!red](0,0)--(0,3)node[pos=0.7,right]{$a\times b$};
\draw (0.6,0) arc [start angle=0,end angle=45,radius=0.6]
node[pos=0.7,right]{$\theta$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]